# Is it possible to clone an existing VM (not template) using terraform provider vsphere

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create a new VM using an existing VM.

For reasons beyond my control - i can not use a template to do this. Is there anyway i could achieve this using terraform - provider vsphere.  I have found samples to do this using a template.

Unfortunately, i haven't found any guidance on using an existing VM.

Comment: It requires vCenter and looks like it's documented here https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/virtual_machine.html#cloning-and-customization-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, i found that "VM clone" could be done using Terraform and it doesn't have to be a temple. You could use same  config that is used for Template clone for VM clone as well.

```
data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
  name = "my-vm-clone-test"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}
```

Where `my-vm-clone-test` is a VM.